# Laser beam receiver

Tags: experimental-physics, laser

Problem: I have an object that can move in the $x,\,y,\,z$ direction. The goal is to measure the $x,y$ variation as the object travels along the $z$ axis. Typically the distance traveled is less than $50 \rm m$. Typical the variations in $x,y$ is $\pm20\,\rm cm$; the accuracy required is to $\pm1\,\rm cm$. The speed is slow at 1 or 2 metres per second. The medium through which the object travels maybe water / wet would this change the answer. It is not a controlled environment so human eye safety is important.

My question is what recording device would you suggest if the object has a laser beam attached pointing in the $z$ direction ?

Even a hint at what technology I should be looking at would help - I've heard of laser microphone, holographic plate, laser sensors but none seem to fit my problem.

Comment: What kind of budget restrictions?

Comment: What is the power output of the laser, like a pencil laser, slide projector type size?  http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/detecting-laser-light.20684/

Comment: There is a huge engineering market for optical tracking and motion capture. These are non-trivial products and if you have to ask about it here (which is the wrong forum), then I have to assume that you don't have the expertise to build something yourself. I would suggest to search for "motion capture" and see who can either sell a stock product to you or build a custom product to your specs.

Comment: Thanks. (1) This is a one off product, so price is not the issue. I will be purchasing the components myself. Let's say £1000. (2) Power output has to be safe for humans and basically what the receiver needs. (3) Thanks for the motion capture advise. That was my second option and I will be pursuing that too but was hoping for the laser beam approach.